# web2py form with list:reference not working with {{=form}}

Tags: python, forms, web2py, foreign-key-relationship, web2py-modules

Using web2py, I am having trouble submitting (?) a form based on a table using list:reference. I have a table *db.game* that references to *db.game_events* in one of its columns called *game_event*.

The form for *db.game* is accepted, but when I try to reach the data in the column *game_events*, that uses list:reference reffering to db.game_events, the column is empty according to the built in web2py grid.

**I can see that the information is correctly posted to the database,** showing the items in brackets in the supposedly empty column. Since I am using the built in web2py grid, I am assuming the collection of the rows is correct and that the problem lies elsewhere.

If I use the "Add record to database"-titled button in the web2py console (the black button with the plus-sign), and use the form there, the game_events column shows the items.

**So; if I try to use {{=form}} in the application, the *game_event*-column is treated as empty, but if I use the built in "Add record to database", the information is there. The question is simply; why can I not use {{=form}} for *db.game* anywhere in the application, when the built in form works fine?** I have tried to simply use {{=form}} and not custom.

To make it even more confusing, if I edit any game in *db.game* in the web2py grid, and press "submit" without altering any information, the *game_event* column in the rows for *db.game* correctly show the *game_events*.

I have been stuck on this forever, I really would appreciate help! Thanks.

Code in db.py

```
db.define_table(
    'game',
    Field('name', label='Tävlingsnamn'),
    Field('status', requires=IS_IN_SET(define_game_status),default='started'),
    Field('registration_start_date', 'date', requires = IS_DATE(format=('%Y-%m-%d')),label=T('Registrering öppnar')),
    Field('registration_end_date', 'date', requires = IS_DATE(format=('%Y-%m-%d')),label=T('Registrering stänger')),
    Field('start_date','date',requires = IS_DATE(format=('%Y-%m-%d')),label=T('Start date')),
    Field('end_date','date',requires = IS_DATE(format=('%Y-%m-%d')),label=T('End date')),
    Field('tracs_available','integer', requires=IS_IN_SET(define_track_amount), widget=div_radio_widget, label=T('Tracks')),
    Field('tracs_available_sprint','integer', requires=IS_IN_SET(define_track_amount), widget=div_radio_widget, label=T('Sprint tracks')),
    Field('game_type', requires=IS_IN_SET(define_game_type),default='Inactive', label=T('Type of event')),
    Field('description','text',label=T('Description')),
    Field('game_event',type='list:reference db.game_events', label='Tävlingsgren'),
    format = '%(name)s')

db.game.game_event.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'game_events.id','%(name)s',multiple=True)

db.define_table(
    'event_class',
    Field('name'),
    format = '%(name)s')

db.define_table(
    'game_events',
    Field('name'),
    Field('class_name', requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.event_class.name,'%(name)s')),
    Field('event_type', requires=IS_IN_SET(define_game_event_types)),
    format ='%(id)s')
```

Code in the controller registration.py

```
#FORM GAMES
def create_game():
    #Form handling  
    #FORM
    form = SQLFORM(db.game)
    request.vars._formname = 'game'

    form.custom.widget.name.update(_placeholder="ex Skelleftespelen") 

    #Registration of results in view            
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session, formname='game'):    
            print("accepted")
            response.flash = 'Tävlingen har skapats!'
            #game_rows = db(db.game).select(orderby=db.game.name)
            return dict(form=form)    

    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors' 

    return dict(form=form)
```

Code in the view create_game.html

```
  <div class="game_name">
            <h4>
                Tävling
            </h4> 
                {{=form.custom.begin}}
                Namn <div>{{=form.custom.widget.name}}</div>      
                Första anmälningsdag <div>{{=form.custom.widget.registration_start_date}}</div>
                Sista anmälningsdag <div>{{=form.custom.widget.registration_end_date}}</div>
                Första tävlingsdag <div>{{=form.custom.widget.start_date}}</div>
                Sista tävlingsdag <div>{{=form.custom.widget.end_date}}</div>
                Sort <div>{{=form.custom.widget.game_type}}</div>
                Sort <div>{{=form.custom.widget.status}}</div>         
                Löparbanor <div>{{=form.custom.widget.tracs_available}}</div>
                Sprintbanor <div>{{=form.custom.widget.tracs_available_sprint}}</div> 
                Beskrivning och/eller information <div>{{=form.custom.widget.description}}</div>          
      Grenar</br></br>
      <p style="background:#FFE066; font-weight:bold;">
          Notera: för att välja grenar måste samtliga önskade grenar att markeras med ctrl + musklick.
        </p>
                <div>{{=form.custom.widget.game_event}}</div>               
                <span id="submit_result">{{=form.custom.submit}}</span>
                {{=form.custom.end}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `reference` or `list:reference` field, if you don't specify the `requires` attribute within the call to `Field()`, you will get a default `requires` attribute (i.e., validator) as well as a default `represent` attribute that controls how the field is displayed in forms and the grid. However, in order to get the default `requires` and `represent` attributes, you must define the referenced table *before* defining the referencing field (otherwise, the referencing field does not have enough information to create the validator and `represent` attributes, both of which incorporate the `format` attribute of the referenced table).

So, just move the definition of `db.game_events` so it comes before the definition of `db.game`. Also, in that case, there is no need to explicitly set the value of `db.game.game_event.requires`, as it will be assigned a default value exactly the same as the one you are assigning.

More generally, if you don't like the default representation of a field's values in forms/grids, you can always set the field's `represent` attribute to control the display.

As an aside, prefer `type='list:reference game_events'` over `type='list:reference db.game_events'` (the latter works but is not officially supported).

Comment: Hm, even after I have changed the order in db.py and use type='list:reference game_events', it still does not work properly. The form submits without errors, the information is clearly in the database when I use the database administration to check, but the game_events row is still treated as if it's empty. For some reason I can still only use the web2py-console button to add games with game_events that I can reach in the controller, not a {{=form}}. This problem really baffles me...

Comment: *it's not the game_events row that is treated as empty, I mean the game_events column in the game-table.

Comment: You will need to update your question and show the code you are using. You mention using a grid, but you show no code creating or displaying a grid. You also mention a problem using `{{=form}}`, but you show no code where that `form` object is generated, nor is it clear how that is relevant if the problem is with a grid/table display (unless the `form` object is a grid). Please clarify exactly what code you are using and exactly what you see where.